# consistency of RK method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I have this question which I think I don't really understand well.

> Consider the IVP
>
> \begin{align} y'(x) &= f(x,y), \quad x \in [x_0 , x_M] \\ 
> y(x_0) &= y_0 \end{align}
>
> Give an example of a consistent $\mathcal{O}(h^3)$ accurate
>   three-stage RK method. Justify your answer.

I really don't understand what should I do here. Can anyone please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know any consistent $O(h^2)$ accurate examples to compare with?

Answer (score 1):

Per https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/low-order-RK.pdf, the third order conditions found 1901 by W.Kutta, are

\begin{align}
&&b_1+b_2+b_3&=1\\
&& b_2c_2+b_3c_3&=\frac12\\
&& b_2c_2^2+b_3c_3^2&=\frac13\\
\text{ and }&&
b_3a_{32}c_2&=\frac16
\end{align}

Any solution gives a valid 3rd order method
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
0\\
c_2&a_{21}\\
c_3&a_{31}&a_{32}\\
\hline
&b_1&b_2&b_3
\end{array}
explicitly named are the RK3 method and Heun's 3rd order method.

---

For a demonstration of the order (and numerical convergence) of a third order method see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3058957/115115

Comment: how it`s consistent ? please explain it to me ...

Comment: Because it has order 3. Check your definitions, consistent means that the method has at least order 1, which means $c_i=\sum_ja_{ij}$ and $\sum b_i=1$.

Comment: If we define the consistency by $\lim_{h\to0} \phi (x_n,y_n;h)= f(x_n,y_n)$ how can I prove it here ? can you at least give me how to write Taylor`s expansion?

Comment: For Runge-Kutta, one-step methods, this really comes back to the local truncation error order 1. For multi-step method you need additionally zero-order stability

Comment: I cannot use zero-stability here since I was asked to use Taylor`s theorem and not zero-stability

Comment: I know. Your are also expected to give a Runge-Kutta method, not a multi-step method.

Comment: any help please?